# How to keep repetitive elements in R using intersect()?

Tags: r

I have two vectors, called `a` and `b`, but some elements in vector `a` are repeated.
I want to compute the intersect of `a` and `b`, but in the result, I also want to have repetition of the element that are in intersect of `a` and `b`

The example and expected output are here :

```
> a<-c("a","a", "c")
> b<-c("a", "c")
```

what I get with `intersect()`

```
> intersect(a,b)
[1] "a" "c"
```

What I expect to get :

```
>[1] "a"  "a"   "c"
```

would someone help me to implement this in R ?

Comment: Your example is wrong, actually.  Now, if you had `x<-c(1,1,2,3)` and `y<-c(1,1,1,3)`  then the intersection would be `1 1 3` .

Comment: Why do you only get two "a"s in your return? There's two in your 'a' variable and another in your 'b'. Should your function be symmetric so that myintersect(a,b) is the same as myintersect(b,a) - and is the order important?

Comment: The two comments above are important and the question cannot be answered unambiguously until you clarify what the assumptions are about your intersection.

Comment: I suspect "some elements in a may be repeated" means "no elements in b will be repeated" which makes for easier solutions. But who knows? The OP, but they're not telling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem description is not very clear. Maybe this:

```
a<-c("a","a", "c", "d")
b<-c("a", "c", "d", "d", "e")

i <- intersect(a, b)
r <- apply(rbind(table(a)[i], 
                 table(b)[i]),
           2, max)
rep(names(r), r)
#[1] "a" "a" "c" "d" "d"
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be three "d"s in the intersection of a and b there? One from a and two from b?

Comment: @Spacedman - seems should be just two "d"s etc, look question example. what he want is to get each char with its max occurrences not matter in which vector.

Answer (score 2):

This will made the job. the first argument of rep is the sorted intersection and the second argument is the calculated from the parallel maximum of the counts of elements in `a` that are also in `b` and the counts of elements in `b` that are also in `a`.

```
   rep(sort(intersect(a, b)), pmax(table(a[a %in% b]), table(b[b %in% a])))
   # [1] "a" "a" "c" "c"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with the disclaimer that I'm the package author:   use `vecsets` package.

Now the reasoning:  the standard `intersect`, `union`, etc. functions operate under the rules of Algebra, which state that sets contain distinguishable elements, i.e. no "repeats."  But for counting purposes and wackos like myself,  I wrote versions which allow you to pretend that each instance of , say "a" , is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Changed it to some ugly solution

```
unlist(lapply(intersect(a, b), function(x) rep(x, max(length(a[a %in% x]), length(b[b %in% x])))))
```

Comment: won't be good in case both have double values, i.e:
`b<-c("a","c","c")`
`a<-c("a","a", "c")`

the result will be  `"a" "a" "c"` instead of `"a" "a" "c" "c"`

Comment: @webSpider, your example works fine with my code

Comment: Like @webSpider said: this fails for a variety of duplications. I tried that before writing the but-tugly code in `vecsets` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, webSpider example gives the correct result, so I don't know what you mean

Comment: Oh, he want's the repetition of them both. Thought he wants only a

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, changed it to something ugly that works :)